# Android multiple release in the pipe

Tags: android, google-play

We have a release (versionCode 100) that with a status "completed" in android that is not made with rollout staged. That's mean all our users will get the app but that's not what we want.
This release (versionCode 100) is waiting to be published by us.

If we release another one (versionCode 101) with rollout staged, does the previous (versionCode 100) will be canceled ?

Comment: If you have version 100 already on 100% out and then start slowly rolling out 101, no. 100 will still be there for the rest of the people that are not the part of the rollout.

Comment: "This release (versionCode 100) is waiting to be published by us." what does that mean, if it has "a status "completed 100%""?

Comment: sorry for the confusion with "completed" and "100%". i remove "100%". With https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher i can check the my release and the status of this release was returning "completed".

Comment: according to @TheLibrarian answer the best way will be  to release the same code as versionCode 100 and then create another release with the rollout staged.

Comment: What I mean that if you start rolling out 101. There still will be people that are going to get 100 because "rolling out" in this context is understood as "Staged rollout" which releases the update to only some % of users. What you are sort of describing does happen when you replace staged rollout release with another staged rollout release (but you HAVE TO release it to higher % of users than the cancelled/previous release.